# How to pass an array of BLOB to a stored oracle procedure?

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

I am allowing user to upload multiple files to my database. These file contents must be stored in my oracle database as BLOB.

How can i write a oracle procedure to do this ? (I have a little knowledge of Oracle stored procedures) ?

Once this is done how can i use the stored procedure in java using jdbc's CallableStatement ?

Please help.

Comment: 1. my procedure is:

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to create the type that will contain the table of BLOB:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tab_blobs AS TABLE OF BLOB;
```

In Java, you have to rely on the STRUCT type provided by Oracle sql.
You will create a STRUCT that will contain the array of BLOB to store into the DB.

The code would look like the following:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver;
import oracle.sql.ARRAY;
import oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor;
import oracle.sql.STRUCT;
import oracle.sql.StructDescriptor;

public class ArrayDemo
{

    public static void passArray()
        throws SQLException
    {
        Connection conn = new OracleDriver().defaultConnection();

        byte[] fileInByteArray = "value".getBytes();
        StructDescriptor itemDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("BLOB", conn);

        Object[] itemAtributes = new Object[] {};
        STRUCT itemObject1 = new STRUCT(itemDescriptor, conn, itemAtributes);

        itemAtributes = new Object[] {};
        STRUCT itemObject2 = new STRUCT(itemDescriptor, conn, itemAtributes);

        STRUCT[] idsArray = { itemObject1, itemObject2 };

        ArrayDescriptor descriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("IDS_TABLE", conn);

        ARRAY array_to_pass = new ARRAY(descriptor, conn, idsArray);

        OraclePreparedStatement ps = (OraclePreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement("begin getInfo(:x); end;");

        ps.setARRAY(1, array_to_pass);
        ps.execute();

    }
}
```

But why don't you simplify the handling by iterating on the files, inserting them one after the other:

```
public static void insererBlob(String name, String path) {
   File file = new File(path);
   try{
      //link to DB
      Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("url","user","password");

      //link to file
      FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);

      //prepare the SQL instruction
      String sql = "INSERT INTO file_table VALUES (?, ?)";
      PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

      //blob insertion
      statement.setString(1, name);
      statement.setBinaryStream(2, stream, (int)file.length());
      statement.executeUpdate();

    }catch(Exception e){
       //ERROR SQL, IO, etc .
    }finally {
       //close connection ?
    }
}
```

Comment: what is "value".getBytes();

Comment: It's supposed to be the file, which you convert to byte[].

Answer (score 0):

Here is another attempty to help you.
You can find more info from oracle here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/e10788/connect.htm#CHDGHFCG
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/

Also, example taken from (website of great help at the time i had to do it):
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/blob.html

```
public void addRowToCoffeeDescriptions(
    String coffeeName, String fileName)
    throws SQLException {

    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    try {
        Clob myClob = this.con.createClob();
        Writer clobWriter = myClob.setCharacterStream(1);
        String str = this.readFile(fileName, clobWriter);
        System.out.println("Wrote the following: " +
            clobWriter.toString());

        if (this.settings.dbms.equals("mysql")) {
            System.out.println(
                "MySQL, setting String in Clob " +
                "object with setString method");
            myClob.setString(1, str);
        }
        System.out.println("Length of Clob: " + myClob.length());

        String sql = "INSERT INTO COFFEE_DESCRIPTIONS " +
                     "VALUES(?,?)";

        pstmt = this.con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.setString(1, coffeeName);
        pstmt.setClob(2, myClob);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException sqlex) {
        JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(sqlex);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("Unexpected exception: " + ex.toString());
    } finally {
        if (pstmt != null)pstmt.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is my code hope you got your answer:

1. from java code:

   ```
           try {Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
           String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl";
           Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, db_user, password);
           System.out.println("Connected to database");

           SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
           Date now = new java.sql.Date(simpleDateFormat.parse("12/02/2001").getTime());

           String command2 = "{call USER1(?,?,?,?)}";

           String path;
           File[] roots = File.listRoots();
           path=roots[0].getPath()+"dfg.jpg";
           System.out.println("path: " + path);
           //shows drives in you computer
           for(int i = 0; i < roots.length ; i++){
               System.out.println("drive: " + roots[i].getPath());

       }

           CallableStatement insertStatment = con.prepareCall(command2);

           insertStatment.setInt(1, 18);
           insertStatment.setString(2, "ankssaait");
           insertStatment.setDate(3, now);


           File file = new File(path);
         //link to file
           FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);

           insertStatment.setBinaryStream(4, stream,(int)file.length());;
           System.out.println("onExecute: "+ insertStatment.executeUpdate());

           insertStatment.close();

           System.out.println("done");


       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   ```
2. my tablei is:

   CREATE TABLE "ANKIT"."O_USER" 
   (    "NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
   "GENDER" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
   "DESIGNTION" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
   "YEAR" INTERVAL YEAR (2) TO MONTH, 
   "ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
   "DOB" DATE, 
   "PROOF" CLOB, 
   "ADDRESS" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
   "TELEPHONE" NUMBER, 
   "RAW1" RAW(20), 
   "IMAGE" BLOB, 
    CONSTRAINT "O_USER_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID"));
3. my procedure is:

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE USER1 (U_ID IN o_user.id%TYPE, U_NAME in o_user.name%TYPE, u_DOB in o_user.dob%TYPE, u_image in o_user.image%TYPE) AS BEGIN insert into o_user(id,name,dob,image) values(u_id,u_name,u_dob,u_image); END USER1;
   ```